# what is the "browser chrome"?

Tags: html, css, browser

The following quote is from O'Reilly Definitive Guide to CSS:

> Mozilla and related browsers use CSS to affect the presentation of the browser chrome itself

What is actually meant by the word "chrome" in this context?  Is it simply the display area?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the chrome is the UI of the actual browser not just the content shown in the page, the themeable bits, like the buttons, menus, tabs, etc

Answer (score 3):

**browser chrome**
‘`Browser chrome` is a euphemism for the graphical framework and elements of the web browser window.

‘Browser chrome’ is not to be confused with `Google Chrome` – which is a web browser.

Chrome includes the web browser:

- title bar,
- toolbar buttons: ‘Back’, ‘Forward’, ‘Stop‘, etc.,
- horizontal and vertical scrollbars,
- status bar: the strip at the bottom of the browser window, and the window frame.

Browser chrome can be modified through the use of ‘skins’; (usually) third-party software extensions that can be used to customise colour, graphical treatment and interface metaphor.

For more reading [Browser and GUI Chrome](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/browser-and-gui-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Browsers are User Interface. With the file menu and setting menu ect It also includes back forward and refresh.

At the botton of the page it contains the status bar how much is loaded ect.

It also can include the minimise maximise and the close buttons. Exlcuding the webpage content.